# Make clickable the whole block with <a> element

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, joomla

I want that the whole block be possible to click when hover the cursor over, to click on a link to go the link.

Example:

### [image]

How this now:

### [image]

The code of the component is:

```
<li<?php echo strlen($item->custom_tags) ? ' class="'.$item->custom_tags.'"' : ''; ?> data-mosaic-item>
<div class="sprocket-mosaic-item" data-mosaic-content>
    <?php echo $item->custom_ordering_items; ?>
    <div class="sprocket-padding">
        <?php if ($item->getPrimaryImage()) :?>
        <div class="sprocket-mosaic-image-container">
            <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?><a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>"><?php endif; ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryImage()->getSource(); ?>" alt="" class="sprocket-mosaic-image" />
            <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?>
                <span class="sprocket-mosaic-hover"></span>
                <span class="sprocket-mosaic-hovercontent"><span>+</span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="sprocket-readmore"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if (count($item->custom_tags_list)) : ?>
            <ul class="sprocket-mosaic-tags">
            <?php
                foreach($item->custom_tags_list as $key => $name){
                    echo ' <li class="sprocket-tags-'.$key.'">'.$name.'</li>';
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="sprocket-mosaic-head">
            <?php if ($item->getTitle()): ?>
            <h2 class="sprocket-mosaic-title">
                <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()): ?><a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>"><?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $item->getTitle();?>
                <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()): ?></a><?php endif; ?>
            </h2>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($parameters->get('mosaic_article_details')): ?>
            <div class="sprocket-mosaic-infos">
                <span class="author"><?php //echo $item->getAuthor(); ?></span>

                <!-- 
                <i class="icon-time"></i> 
                <span class="mosaic-date">
                    <?php //echo $item->getDate();?>
                </span> -->

                <?php if($item->getDate()): ?>
                <!-- Date created -->
                <span class="mosaic-date">
                    <i class="icon-time"></i>
                    <?php echo JHTML::_('date', $item->getDate(), JText::_('d M Y')); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>


            </div>

            <?php endif; ?>



        </div>




        <div class="sprocket-mosaic-text">
            <?php echo $item->getText(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So i want the entire block of red border to be possible to click

Comment: I would not do this with a tags, rather make the whole div a link with onmouseclick and have that link to where you want.

Answer (score 1):

My english is not the best, so I hope that I got you right:

you want one div-container to be clickable?

if that is what you want, why don't you wrap the div container by your link

Code Example:

```
<a href="...">
<div>
//Additional Code in here
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: It's not W3-compliant. `div` shouldn't be inside `a`, while `a` should be inside a `div`. Therefore +0

Comment: @Scorpion it is , in HTML5 and as long as A stands aside block elements.  see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a read down to **changes in html5**

Comment: I don't know if it is or not... it works, but, if you want to turn it around, you can put the <a> inside the <div> EDIT: the css of the elements depends on how the elements inside are used.. sry for my incomplete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with two ways - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zah6P/).

The upper one uses jQuery .on('click' and it points to a styled div.

The lower one changes an anchor tag to block, adds a picture and text, then on click redirects.

I'm sure there are other ways.

HTML

```
<div class='wholeblock'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/DgYUsKY.jpg?1' />
    <div>Minions are fun</div>
    <div>Minions are happy</div>
    <div>There are many Minions</div>
</div>

<a href='www.stackoverflow.com' class='wholeblock'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/DgYUsKY.jpg?1' />
    <div>Minions are fun</div>
    <div>Minions are happy</div>
    <div>There are many Minions</div>
</a>
```